# Ubuntu installation loading forever on "Where are you" screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation

I have a Dell Windows 10 system with 256 SSD and BitLocker turned on my C: and I also have a U:(not Encrypted) empty for Ubuntu installation. I booted my pendrive with rufus in "GPT partition UEFI mode" but While installing the installation gets stuck for a long time at "Where are you" screen. I got impatient and cancelled it. Please provide a solution

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: BitLocker turn off. Later, after install Ubuntu, Bitlocker turn on

Comment: I tried turning off bitlocker but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is I tried updating Windows 10 from 1703 to 1709 and tried installing it. It worked. It doesn't make any sense but it worked.